# How can I set only the outer booleans of a 2d array to false?

Tags: language-agnostic, loops

If I have a 2d array like:

`boolean[][] map = new boolean[50][50];`

How can I set the outer edge of booleans to true only in a loop?

So, for the following array:

```
0 0 0 0 0 0   
0 0 0 0 0 0   
0 0 0 0 0 0   
0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0
```

You would have:

```
1 1 1 1 1 1
1 0 0 0 0 1 
1 0 0 0 0 1
1 0 0 0 0 1
1 1 1 1 1 1
```

I'm new to programming and I've been struggling to get this to work?

I thought possibly using 2 loops like:

```
for(int i = 0; i < map.length; i++)
{
    map[i][0] = true;
    map[i][map[0].length] = true;
}

for(int i = 0; i < map[0].length; i++)
{
    map[0][i] = true;
    map[map.length][i] = true;
}
```

But honestly I'm not sure if this is the correct approach?

Comment: use map.length-1 and map[0].length-1 when you are indexing the array

Comment: if it is a square you only need one for loop, if it is a rectangle it is easiest to use 2 loops as you have

Comment: that is, if you are sure that per default they are initialized to false. And that is not always true I'd say. If you are not sure of that you need the for in for loop.

Comment: the question implied to me that we are starting from a zeroed array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for( int i = 0; i<maxx; i++)
{
  for( int j = 0; j<maxy; j++)
  {
    if( i==0 || i == maxx-1 || j == 0 || j == maxy-1 )
    {
       //Write 1
    }
    else
    {
       //Write 0
    }
  }
}
```

This is probably not the best possible code, but it demonstrates easily how to achieve it:

Write something in all fields. 

If the field is:

1. At the top or bottom of the 2d array
2. to the left or right

write a **1**, otherwise a **0**.

The question is, when it is at the top or bottom? 

At the time the line-index (**i**) is either 0 or highest possible.

The same counts for the column index (**j**).

Comment: This will consider every cell in the array, i wonder if there is a more efficient way to do this

Comment: as I wrote: there are more efficient ways. But the example should show very clearly the way you could go when tackling the problem (at least in my opinion).

Answer (score 1):

```
for( int i = 0; i<50; i++)
{
  map[i][0] = 1;
  map[i][49] = 1;
  map[0][i] = 1;
  map[49][i] = 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming the structure is already initialized with 0s.

```
integer max = 50;
boolean[][] map = new boolean[max][max];
for ( integer x=0;x<max;x++) {
   map[0,x] =1;
   map[max-1,x] =1;
   map[x,0] =1;
   map[max-1,x] =1;
}
```

Problem: this initializes the corners more than once ..

Comment: Personally I didn't think it was worth the bother to worry about doing the corners more than once, but if it concerns you, change your loop to start from x=1 and adapt the indices slightly as unwind did

Comment: I agree, it's not a problem .. but since the OP seems to be a beginner, I wanted to point it out explicitly. gnibbler coded around this .. but had to sacrifice some "readability"

Answer (score 0):

In Java:

```
int firstRow = 0;
int lastRow = map.length - 1;
int width = map[0].length;

for (int i=0; i<width; i++) {
    map[firstRow][i] = true;
}
System.arrayCopy (map[firstRow], 0, map[lastRow], 0, width);

int lastColumn = width - 1;
for (int i=1; i<lastRow; i++) {
    map[i][0] = map[i][lastColumn] = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is of course limited by the number of writes you must do, which are O(n) where n is the side length of the matrix, assuming the matrix is square.

You can of course simplify the code to only touch the outer elements:

```
for i in xrange(0, n - 1):
  matrix[0][i] = true
  matrix[i][-1] = true
  matrix[-1][-(i + 1)] = true
  matrix[-(i + 1)][0] = true
```

This does four writes per iteration of the loop. I think I did the indexing correctly now, the idea is to do the writes in this order, for the case where n=4 (apologies for the stunning ASCII graphics):

```
 0120
 2  1
 1  2
 0210
```

So, you can see that each side only goes from 0 to n - 2, inclusive. This is expressed in Python as `for i in xrange(0, n -1)`.

Comment: If that is python you can just use [-1] instead of [n-1]

Comment: @gnibbler: Aarggh, true, I always forget. :)

Answer (score 0):

In Python it is very easy

```
X=10
Y=5
m=[[1]*X]+[[1]+[0]*(X-2)+[1]]*(Y-2)+[[1]*X]
for row in m:
    print row
```

outputs:

```
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

Here is the breakdown

```
[1]*X       # gives us a list of X 1's [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1] in this case

[0]*(X-2)   # gives us a list of (X-2) 0's [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0] in this case
```

so

```
[[1]*x]     # gives us an 1 by X array [[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]]

[[1]+[0]*(X-2)+[1]]  # gives a 1 by X array [[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1]]
```

we multiply the array above to give Y-2 identical lines

and then add another row of 1's to the bottom

Comment: `m=[[1]*X]+[[1]+[0]*(X-2)+[1]]*(Y-2)+[[1]*X]` - yes. Very easy. Very readable. :-)